# c# Button Array ContextMenu repeats menu items for each Button's Click

Tags: c#, contextmenu

As I said at the topic I declared a Button Array and gave properties in "for" loop as you can see below.

```
for (int a = 0; a < row; a++) { 
for (int b = 0; b < column; b++) { 
    buttons[a, b] = new Button(); 
    buttons[a, b].Click += new EventHandler(buttons_Click); 
    buttons[a, b].ContextMenu = MyCM.CM; this.Controls.Add(buttons[a, b]); 
    } 
}
```

Here is the Click Event of the buttons to call Context Menu

```
private void buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
Button u = sender as Button; 
MyCM.contextmenum(u); 
}
```

Here is the my Context Menu class "MyContextMenu" "MyCM"

```
public class MyContextMenu { 
Button u = new Button(); 
public ContextMenu CM = new ContextMenu(); 
public void contextmenum(Button u) { 
    MenuItem m1 = new MenuItem("Question"); 
    MenuItem m2 = new MenuItem("Answer"); 
    CM.MenuItems.Add(m1); 
    CM.MenuItems.Add(m2); 
    m1.Click += new EventHandler(m1_Click); 
    m2.Click += new EventHandler(m2_Click); 
    this.u.ContextMenu = CM; 
    this.u = u; 
} 
    private void m1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { } 
    private void m2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

That is the question: When I right click a button, Context Menu is appearing as "Answer" "Qestion". However, When I right click to another button Context Menu is appearing as "Answer" "Qestion" "Answer" "Qestion". For third button click menu items repeats itself 3 times and becomes "Answer" "Qestion" "Answer" "Qestion" "Answer" "Qestion"..

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: You're not clearing the contextmenu and instead appending to it each time which results in the options accumulating

Comment: Yes, at some point you need to:  `CM.MenuItems.Clear();`.

Comment: Are you trying to SHARE the same ContextMenu across all buttons?  If so, create it ONCE and add the menus in the Constructor of your MyContextMenu Class, then just assign it to the Button passed in.  Don't add the menu items each time as the others have already pointed out...

Comment: Giving a button a context menu is rather unintuitive.  No user will ever guess that right-clicking a button will do something useful.  Do write a constructor for that class, that's where the code that's now in contextmenum() belongs.